# How to add malicious or black hole nodes in ONE simulator?

Tags: dtn, one-simulator

I am trying to implement black hole attack using ONE simulator. How do I add malicious or black hole nodes in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new routing module that doesn't start any new transfers in the update method (see for example [EpidemicRouter](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/blob/c9404f105268109cc9a7269c51f756514885f62e/src/routing/EpidemicRouter.java#L35)). Depending on which routing module you want to use for the non-malicious nodes, you may need to make your new module a subclass of that module.